# What is the range on singularity grenades?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just picked up my first singularity grenade that pulls enemies in before blowing up ! [ it's amazing ] I have tried testing how close they have to be to enemies to pull them in, but haven't had any conclusive results (either the grenades ended up right on top of them or too far away)

What is the max range on singularity grenades to pull enemies in? (Not blast radius)

Comment: I also would like to know if the weight of the enemy determines how far away they have to be to not be pulled in

Comment: @Kecoey I think the weight (well, mass!) of the characters determines how much they're pulled in as opposed to the distance. I'm sure I've seen two enemies, one big and one small, the same distance from a grenade being affected differently. Don't have proof though.

Comment: Also, what does the range value refer to?  Is it the explosion radius, singularity radius, or both?

Comment: @MBraedley listed radius on the item card is the blast radius. The sigularity's pull is *significantly* wider

Answer (score 1):

I have also tested this and figured it was around 10 yards. Tried to look myself for some info about the grenades but all I found was the Borderlands Wiki page that contains some information about each type of grenade.

[B2 Grenades](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Hyperion)

From the table you can see that the Singularity grenade is Manufactured by Hyperion if you continue the Wiki there are some more infos about Hyperion like damage/accuracy. 
[Hyperion](http://www.bl2wiki.com/Hyperion)

I hope this info will give you a little more you can work on when testing them.